# When ifdef is really needed for logging

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a c++ code that it's quite old. In this code I can find:

```
#ifdef LOG
LOG_DEBUG(bla bla bla);
#endif
```

and in the debug header file:

```
#ifdef LOG
LOG_DEBUG(X) ....code....
#else
LOG_DEBUG(X) (void) 0
#endif
```

Now my question is: is there any reason why the ifdef is repeated in every statement in the code? I guess this kind of strategy can be really worth just in one case, i.e. when I need to perform some hard preliminary work just to log something.

```
#ifdef LOG
int a = mySuperComplicatedFunction();
....other worth code here with "a"...
LOG_DEBUG(the result here);
#endif
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: BTW probably `do {} while(0)` would be slightly better than `(void) 0` for the `#else` case.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Why?

Comment: If `LOG_DEBUG` should work "as if" it were a `void` function, this ensures that it interacts in the same way with the surroundings in the two cases. In particular, you didn't show the code for the other case, but I'm pretty much sure that `LOG_DEBUG(x) + 5;` doesn't work when `LOG` is defined, while it does when it's not defined. In general, if you use `do{ ... } while(0)` (notice: not just a plain `{ ... }` scope) in all your statement-like macros you don't go wrong (particularly for multi-statement ones).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now my question is: is there any reason why the ifdef is repeated in every statement in the code?

No, it’s completely redundant in those cases, you’re not missing anything. In particular, you correctly identified the one case in which it’s actually needed.